# Notice of Conversion for 3(a)10

Tags: united-states, financial-literacy, stock-valuation, news

I am trying to figure out what this means.

Is this good or bad?

http://markets.businessinsider.com/news/stocks/metrospaces-announces-that-it-will-not-honor-notice-of-conversion-for-3-a-10-due-to-potential-fraud-against-the-company-1018537763

Also i am not sure if that is related to this:

https://globenewswire.com/news-release/2018/03/05/1414775/0/en/Metrospaces-Announces-Cancellation-of-1-6-Billion-of-Common-Shares.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://repository.law.umich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1039%26context%3Dmbelr&ved=2ahUKEwij0PLeqvHZAhWIOY8KHXDDCw4QFjAAegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw11TuXOchMvsHK2Dzm3iHz1

> The Section 3(a)(10) exemption of the Securities Act of 1933 is meant
>   to exempt securities transactions where a fairness hearing by a judge or
>   government agency’s ruling replaces the usual SEC registration require-
>   ments. Recently, there has been a rise in 3(a)(10) financing schemes, where
>   a third party investor, what I call a “3(a)(10) financier,” will offer to
>   purchase the outstanding debts of a company from its creditors in exchange
>   for discounted, and unregistered, shares of stock. In many cases these ex-
>   changes are done with no notification to current shareholders whose value
>   falls precipitously when the 3(a)(10) financier begins not only selling, but
>   through a common clause in these 3(a)(10) financing contracts, also de-
>   manding that the company issue more shares to them at any time. The
>   companies who work with 3(a)(10) financiers have, in some cases, become
>   complicit in the scheme in order to hide these transactions from investors
>   who provide the liquidity for the 3(a)(10) financier sell-offs

Whether it is good or bad, only time will tell. There will be litigation and may take a while to settle.